# Call function inside a class

Tags: python

I have tried to integrate the function `W_Kpower(scpi_comm)` into a class, but I get an error:

```
  keithley = rm.open_resource(instControl(inst_list))
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Could you help me to integrate the function into a class. I need that for the other classes in the future. I'm beginner, so I don't understand all the details of my code.

```
import Tkinter,visa,time
from ttk import *

root = Tkinter.Tk
rm = visa.ResourceManager()

# Split port touple into a list
inst_list = []
str_inst = rm.list_resources()
for i in str_inst:
    inst_list.append(i.split(","))

# Convert list into a string and replace it
def delChar(inst,input_inst):
    str_new = ''.join(str(e) for e in inst_list[input_inst])
    find_char = "()u[]"
    for char in find_char:
        inst = str_new.replace(char,"")
    return inst

def delCharIn(list_del):
    str_new = ''.join(str(e) for e in list_del)
    find_char = "()u[]"
    for char in find_char:
        list_del = str_new.replace(char,"")
    return list_del

# List the instruments and choose one
def instControl(inst):
    new_list = []
    for index in range(len(inst)):
        new_list.append(delCharIn(inst[index]))
    return new_list


#keithley = rm.open_resource(instControl(inst_list))

class InterfaceApp(root):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        root.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):

        frInstrument = Tkinter.Frame(width=800, height=200, bg="", 
                                     colormap="new")
        frInstrument.grid(row=0,sticky='EW')

        separator = Tkinter.Frame(width=800, height=2, bd=1, relief='sunken')
        separator.grid(row=1)

        frSettings = Tkinter.Frame(width=800, height = 400, bg="",
                                   colormap="new")
        frSettings.grid(row=3,sticky='EW')

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(False,False)

        groupInstrument = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frInstrument,
                                             text="Choose an Instruments",
                                             padx = 5, pady=5)
        groupInstrument.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky="EW")
        choices = instControl(inst_list)
        self.choiceVarPower = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.choiceVarPower.set(choices[0])


        inst1 =Combobox(groupInstrument, values = choices,textvariable = 
                                                    self.choiceVarPower)
        inst1.grid(row=0, column=2,sticky="EW",padx=2,pady=2)



        instLabel1 = Tkinter.Label(groupInstrument, text="Power Supply: ")
        instLabel1.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='EW')

        instLabel2 = Tkinter.Label(groupInstrument, text="Multimeter: ")
        instLabel2.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='EW')

        self.choiceVarMulti = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.choiceVarMulti.set(choices[0])
        inst2 = Combobox(groupInstrument, values=choices, textvariable = 
                            self.choiceVarMulti)
        inst2.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='EW',padx=2,pady=2)

        but_start = Tkinter.Button(frSettings,text='Run',
                                command=self.Run)
        but_start.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='EW')
        but_closeInst = Tkinter.Button(frSettings,text="Close all instruments",
                                       command = self.closeInst)
        but_closeInst.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='EW')

    def W_KPower(scpi_comm):
        return self.keithleyPower.write(":syst:loc")
    def closeInst(self):
        W_KPower(":syst:loc")

    def Run(self):
        self.keithleyPower = rm.open_resource(self.choiceVarPower.get())
        self.keithleyMultimeter = rm.open_resource(self.choiceVarMulti.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = InterfaceApp(None)
    app.title("")
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `self` in the method definition here:

```
def W_KPower(scpi_comm):  # this should be def W_KPower(self, scpi_comm)
    return self.keithleyPower.write(":syst:loc")
```

and I think here, you need `self.`:

```
def closeInst(self):
    W_KPower(":syst:loc")  # this should be self.W_KPower(":syst:loc")
```